# Pandas DataFrame: Spread CSV columns to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 2, 3], ['a,b', 5, 6], ['c', 8, 9]])
     0  1  2
0    a  2  3
1  a,b  5  6
2    c  8  9
```

I want to spread the first column to `n` columns (where `n` is the number of unique, comma-separated values, in this case 3). Each of the resulting columns shall be 1 if the value is present, and 0 else. Expected result is:

```
   1  2  a  c  b
0  2  3  1  0  0
1  5  6  1  0  1
2  8  9  0  1  0
```

I came up with the following code, but it seems a bit circuitous to me.

```
>>> import re
>>> dfSpread = pd.get_dummies(df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)).\
        rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('.*_','',x))
>>> pd.concat([df.iloc[:,1:], dfSpread], axis = 1)
```

Is there a built-in function that does just that that I wasn't able to find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `get_dummies`

```
df.set_index([1,2])[0].str.get_dummies(',').reset_index()
Out[229]: 
   1  2  a  b  c
0  2  3  1  0  0
1  5  6  1  1  0
2  8  9  0  0  1
```

Comment: At least I picked the right function... You're essentially setting all other columns as index to 'save' the information, applying the function and setting the index back. That's a great thought-provoking impulse. Thanks ! (waiting 8 more minutes to accept your anser)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pop` + `concat` here for an alternative version of Wen's answer.

```
pd.concat([df, df.pop(df.columns[0]).str.get_dummies(sep=',')], axis=1)

   1  2  a  b  c
0  2  3  1  0  0
1  5  6  1  1  0
2  8  9  0  0  1
```